# Affine convex cone

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I am new to the convex geometry. I recently came across a term *affine convex cone*. Wikipedia mentions that

"An affine convex cone is the set resulting from applying an affine transformation to a convex cone. A common example is translating a convex cone by a point $p: p+C.$ Technically, such transformations can produce non-cones. For example, unless $p=0$, $p+C$ is not a linear cone. However, it is still called an affine convex cone."

My questions are:

$(1)$ Given any compact convex set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a point $b\notin A$, can we always draw two lines from $b$ that support $A$?

$(2)$ Is it possible to draw more than two lines from $b$ that support $A$?

$(3)$ If two lines (assuming we can draw exactly two lines) are $L_1$ and $L_2$. Then is the convex hull of $L_1$ and $L_2$ an affine convex cone at $b$?

**EDIT** Suppose that $A$ contains at least two points such that they do not lie on a line passing through origin at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For (1), if $A$ is a single point (or the ray extending away from $b$) the there is only one support that passes through $b$.

Comment: I see!@copper.hat. Indeed, that is true, even if all the members of $A$ has the same argument. I am editing to make a change in $A$. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: $L_1\cup L_2$ is a cone, taking convex hull preserves cone property

Comment: Will you please elaborate a bit @daw